# Curved <hr> S shape

Tags: php, html, css

I've been searching everywhere, how to make a html/css resonsive S shaped dotted line like this

[image]

So, far it has been the bain of my existence.
I'm trying to avoid SVG at all costs, althought i've also searched how to do it in SVG.
 Can someone help me?

Comment: SVG will be by far the easiest solution here.

Comment: yeah, but how can i figure out the right coordinates and how to make it responsive?

Comment: The S in SVG means Scalable. SVG is innately responsive :D

Comment: @wydtron, I have implemented CSS solution, look into it! [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44029744/2679536)

Answer (score 1):

```css
hr.style-seven {
        height: 150px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
        border-radius: 130px 0px 0px 0px;
 border-top: 1px dashed #8c8c8c;
 margin-right:130px;
}
hr.style-seven:before { 
        display: block;
        content: "";
        height: 150px;
        margin-top: -151px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 130px 0px;
 margin-left:130px;
 margin-right:-130px;
 border-bottom: 1px dashed #8c8c8c;
} 
.box{ height: 500px; margin-top:200px;}
```

```html
<body class="box">
      <hr class="style-seven"/>
</body>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kNB3c/201/)